# Rotate a multiline string

Tags: java

This is a bit of an odd question, but i cant figure out how to do this.
I have a multi-line string which looks like this when printed:

```
xxx$$xx
xxx$$xx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
```

How can I "rotate" it 90 degrees? Desired outcome:

```
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxx$$
```

In my class, each line of the final output string is individually put together then appended with a line break to print the first string (multi line) above.

Comment: Where are your efforts?

Comment: You might look into how to rotate a 2d matrix/array/pixels, the basic principle would probably be the same

Comment: @ArslanAli my efforts? i said i do not know how to do this.. perhaps you could point me in the right direction

Comment: Do you want to take the amount of charackters as the rotating condition (not a square) or the size of the printed charackters (look more like a square)

Comment: @KevinEsche the characters as the rotating condition, the height and width should stay the same, and excess characters ignored

Comment: isn't desired outcome wrong? considering the rotation of 90'

Comment: ok, that seems to be right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that by *rotate* you do not also mean printing the text sideways, you could treat your multi line string as a 2d array of characters.

You could then do something like so:

```
for row in nonRotated
   for column in nonRotated[row]
       rotated[column][row] = nonRotated[row][column]
```

Comment: I think that could potentially throw **ArrayOutOfBoundException**, since row and column can be different;

Comment: The word "column" has three different spellings depending on the ordinality of its usage in the context.

Comment: I'll try add a code example shortly to try and clarify your points.

Comment: so to rotate 90 deg, you swap the rows and columns?

Comment: this is tricky because its not a perfect square, although i suppose i can just trim excess rows/columns

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it's already answered now but I'd do it like this:

```
String[][] testArr = new String[][] { { "a", "b" }, { "a", "a" },
    { "c", "c" } };

System.out.println("Array before:");
for (int i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < testArr[i].length; j++) {
    System.out.print(testArr[i][j]);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
//rotation start
int A = testArr.length;
int B = testArr[0].length;
String[][] arrDone = new String[B][A];
for (int i = 0; i < A; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < B; j++) {
    arrDone[j][A - i - 1] = testArr[i][j];
  }
}
//rotation end
System.out.println("Array afterwards:");
for (int i = 0; i < arrDone.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < arrDone[i].length; j++) {
    System.out.print(arrDone[i][j]);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```